# invoke a linux shell command from Java between two linux system computer

Tags: java, linux, shell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I execute Linux commands on a remote machine using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7950024/how-can-i-execute-linux-commands-on-a-remote-machine-using-java)

In my linux client computer, I am trying to invoke a linux shell on the other linux server.

Then I would show the result on the client computer.

The command looks like this: grep 11111 userId.log

Are there any java open source project can do this?

Comment: Do you have anyway of running any code on the server beforehand? If so its very easy to do with std java libraries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can ssh to the other computer, you can use the [Jsch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) library to do this in java.

Comment: thanks Do you have some examples :)

Comment: @Felix: yes, you can click on a link in the answer above and then click... *Examples*