# run .bat file from other systems java code

Tags: java, eclipse, batch-file

I want to the run the bat file present in the other system through eclipse java.Below is the code to run if the bat file is in our system .

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class batchFile_execution_throught_java {

public static void main(String[] args) {
     Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
     try
     {

     Process p1 = runtime.exec("cmd /c C:\\Users\\root\\Desktop\\sample.bat");
     InputStream is = p1.getInputStream();
     int i = 0;
     while( (i = is.read() ) != -1)
     {
     System.out.print((char)i);
     }

     }
     catch(IOException ioException)
     {
     System.out.println(ioException.getMessage() );
     }
}

}
```

Comment: can't you create a shared folder in windows configuration to point remote computer?

Comment: I need to  run the bat file in other system and get the out put in my eclipse  console

Comment: that does not answer my question... :) please kindly check my answer for further explanation

Comment: Also note that your implementation of handling exec() call and it's streams may hang indefinitely - see http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html

Answer (score 1):

My first try will be to create a shared folder in windows, so you can access to remote file in the same way you do now:

```
 Process p1 = runtime.exec("cmd /c \\alias_of_folder\\sample.bat");
```

---

If create shared folder is not an option, what you need is to open an connection to the other computer from with your Java application.

- [OpenSSH](http://www.openssh.com/java.html) site has information that will give ou `ssh` support in `Java`.
- Also check [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) and it's [examples](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/).

---

**UPDATE** from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7950236/3850595):

> You can also combine `Jsch` with `Expect4j` and this way have a better control on the commands you want to execute ([nice example here](https://nikunjp.wordpress.com/2011/07/30/remote-ssh-using-jsch-with-expect4j/)).

Comment: Note that alias_of_folder will only work as long as there is a drive mapping with that name available for the the user account under which the Java app runs. This is not the case if your Java code runs as a Windows service (ex: running in Tomcat). For this reason it's better to use UNC paths.

Comment: @Dragos, its quite easy to automate the action in windows start... About tomcat... I know, but does not seem relevant for OP

Comment: I don't see how your given example will access anything remote? Looks as it simply accesses some local batch file?